# How to move this span to its own line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I'm trying to move a `span` to a new line.

Here is a [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/RKZwbb) which best illustrates the question.

I have a lot of dynamic content wrapped in `spans`.

**HTML example:**

```
<span class="group">
  <span class="num">500</span>
  <span class="text">TEXT</span>
  <span class="sym">~</span>
  <span class="num2">50</span>
</span>
```

**CSS**:

```
.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: baseline;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Without making changes to the HTML I'd just like to move `.num2` to a new row. I thought adding `display: block` would be sufficient, but it has no effect, possibly due to the flexbox styling?

Would appreciate any advice, cheers.

(**Note**: I'm not too worried about the position of the pseudoelement at the moment)

**SNIPPET:**

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: baseline;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.num,
.text,
.sym {
  margin-left: .3em;
}
.num,
.text {
  display: inline-block;
}
.num2 {
  margin-left: .3em;
  /* display: block; // this doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<span class="group">
  <span class="num">500</span>
  <span class="text">TEXT</span>
  <span class="sym">~</span>
  <span class="num2">50</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `flexbox` *wrap* by adding `flex-wrap: wrap` and *force* `num2` to the next row by adding `flex-basis: 100%` to it.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}

.ideal {
  float: right;
}

.ideal p {
  margin-top: 0; 
}

.ideal p:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid black;
  margin-left: .3em;
}

.working {
  float: left;
}

.head {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: baseline;
  margin-top: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.num,
.text,
.sym {
  margin-left: .3em;
}

.num,
.text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.num2 {
  margin-left: .3em;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.group::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid black;
  margin-left: .3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="working">
  <div class="head red">What I have now</div>
  <span class="group">
  <span class="num">500</span>
  <span class="text">TEXT</span>
  <span class="sym">~</span>
  <span class="num2">50</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The site was in read only mode and I couldn't comment. This is fantastic, thanks so much :)